# Is the Tunnel Fighter stance once per enemy, or how often does it trigger?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, fighting-style

Does the Tunnel Fighter fighting style (from [UA: Light, Dark, Underdark!](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/02_UA_Underdark_Characters.pdf)) trigger multiple times on an enemy who is, for example, running in circles around the character?

If yes, does it trigger every 10 ft. stretch (more than 5 foot movement), or every space after the initial trigger (since each move IS over 5 feet of movement after the grand total is taken into account)?

---

I realize that I misread the UA description of the Tunnel Fighter fighting style. I thought it meant unlimited attacks on 5+ movement within range but nothing to do with regular oppies which used your reaction. I now realize it is completely the opposite (unlimited regular oppies, but the 5+ movement attack uses the reaction)

Comment: Related: [Can a Tunnel Fighter Polearm Master hit the same incoming enemy twice?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110609) and [Does Tunnel Fighter turn an Opportunity Attack into a non-action?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114589)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Unlimited Opportunity Attacks, but only one Reaction for the 5' movement.

[Tunnel Fighter](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/02_UA_Underdark_Characters.pdf) states (emphasis mine):

> As a bonus action, you can enter   a   defensive   stance that lasts   until the   start   of  your    next    turn.   While   in  your    defensive   stance, **you   can make    opportunity attacks without using   your    reaction**, and you can **use   your    reaction    to  make    a   melee   attack  against a   creature    that    moves   more    than    5   feet    while   within  your    reach.**

The main gist of this is that with Tunnel Figher, Opportunity Attacks no longer utilize your single Reaction and therefore you can take as many Opportunity Attacks as have been triggered.

In the case of an enemy "running circles around a character", the following would need to occur:

1. Creature enters your reach
2. Creature moves at least 5' (can expend your one reaction to make a melee attack against them). Note that this is NOT an Opportunity Attack, but simply the use of your single reaction.
3. Creature moves out of your reach and triggers an Opportunity Attack

If the creature chooses to Rinse and Repeat (but why, man, why?!), then the cycle begins for 1 and 3 and skips Step 2 (you still only get one reaction.)

### Unearthed Arcana isn't necessarily balanced

Having unlimited Opportunity Attacks may be unbalanced, and may be why they never made this official. Unearthed Arcana is playtest material, and this particular UA has been out for 3 years with no updates or official release. DM beware :)

Comment: I'm not saying if the enemy leaves the range, I"m saying if the enemy moves an additional 5 or 10 feet after causing the strike, while STILL in range. An example if if the character has a reach weapon, and the enemy tries to pass him, will effectively move about 25 feet while in range

Comment: @user44332 see point 2 for movement within range generating an attack. Those movements don't give opportunity attacks, just that you can use your reaction to make a melee attack.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, thanks. It makes sense